# Modificar checkbox y radiobutton en Genexus

Tags: css, checkbox, genexus, radiobutton, theme

Requiero cambiar el tamaño, el color y la forma de los contornos de los elementos checkbox y radiobutton que utilizo en los webpanel.

¿Alguien puede indicarme qué propiedades necesito modificar en las clases que viene como parte del "theme" de Genexus?

Estoy usando GX 16.11. Al manipular las propiedades del check o del radio en el tema de GX solo altero el marco que rodea al "check" o al "radio".  Quiero deplegar un check màs grande con diferente borde y fondo dependiendo de su estado: hover, selected, checked, disabled. Ya traté de agregar código CSS, agregar "Custom propierties" y montar un tema diferente.. Estoy seguro que algo estoy haciendo mal. La documentación que carece de ejemplos.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: Si bien a tu pregunta le faltan datos importantes como: en que version de genexus estas o imagenes descriptivas de que es lo que queres lograr, te paso info: Para lograr una estetica distinta al default podrias usar UserControls 2.0 ... Tambien a partir de v17 podes usar Unanimo, donde tenes las clases disponibles para modificar y extender los controles de gx. Te dejo links a documentacion: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48382,Unanimo https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39356,Category%3AUser+Control+object

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podría hacer es crear una clase en el atributo o variable que quiere utilizar como checkbox o radiobutton **Class=** Attribute **NuevaClaseCheck**, por defecto se la crea como **External Class = true** en el tema que tenga predeterminado, seguido a este debe agregarla en el nodo Custom **Add Class** le pone el mismo nombre (***NuevaClaseCheck***) y aquí puede ya configurar su clase. También utilizar el **!important** para que tenga mayor prioridad que las que tenga el tema.